# Set data types accepting vales out of the field

Tags: mysql, sql

i am practicing about enum and set data types. By mistake i made a insert query that accept out of collection of set and

my insert query is for set data type i create a table like this:-

```
create table fiddle(
fid set('ham','burger','chicken','pizza') );


/* values entered from the collection*/
 insert into fiddle values('ham'); 
insert into fiddle values('chicken'); 
insert into fiddle values('pizza'); 
/* values entered out of the collection*/
 insert into fiddle values('0');
 insert into fiddle values('1'); 
insert into fiddle values('2'); 
/*....it accept values upto 15 */
 insert into fiddle values('14'); 
insert into fiddle values('15');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27e29/1 //first table
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/705d00/1 //second table

My question is that why it is accepting values out of the collection?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL or SQL Server? Please do not spam with tags just to create extra exposure. The correct query can also differ based on which of these 2 you are using, so please be specific.

Comment: @SchmitzIT I am using mysql